# How to add node_modules as dependencies to package.json?

Tags: reactjs, json, node-modules, npm-install

I want to add these 3 installations to my package.json dependencies:

1. npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
2. npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
3. npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome

I already tried

npm install <@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core> [--save-prod]

which didn´t work.

How do I add this, so that a random person only has to type in "npm install" in order to get all the required modules?

Comment: I t  should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add those three packages as dependencies in your package.json file, you can use the `--save` or `-S` flag with npm install. The `--save` flag is the default behaviour of npm when you install packages, so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

Here's how you can add those packages to your package.json:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Or you can install all of them in a single command like this:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Once you've added these packages to your package.json file, anyone who clones your repository or downloads your project can simply run `npm install` to install all the required modules, including these dependencies.

Comment: It worked, thank you. I somehow must´ve installed these packages without them being added to the package.json folder at my first try.